# Android is it possible to read/open a pdf file in app without any libraries?

Tags: android, pdf

English is not my strong language, but please bear with me.

What is the difference between a PDF Reader and a PDF Viewer ? Some apps and api uses these terms and got me confused.

My second question is, I dont understand how GPL works. From what I read on these libraries like MuPDF, vuDroid, APV, it is free to develop but I have to buy a license to commercialize my app. How does it work if I were to publish my app on the Play Store for Free ? I dont get this, does publishing my app = commercializing ?

My third question, I understand that I am required to publish my source code should I use any of the mentioned libraries due to GPL license, but do I have the option of not publishing my code at all ?

What I want is just to create an app that is able to open a pdf file in my app. Something like an eBook app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, PDF Reader and PDF Viewer are the same - they are both types of programs used to read (=view) pdf files.

If your app is published on app store for free, then its not commercial app, so publishing your app on appstore is not the same as commercializing it.

BTW - Most android users have some kind of program for viewing PDF files pre-installed, so you can just open PDF viewer with intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                try {
                    startActivity(intent);
                } 
                catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(OpenPdf.this, 
                        "No Application Available to View PDF", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

If you want to view PDF files directly in your app (which is probably what you want to do) you can use libraries like you mentioned.

EDIT: If you use GPL library, i think your application also have to be GPL (see [GPL License in closed source application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842776/gpl-license-in-closed-source-application)), but you dont have to buy license.

Comment: Thank you. I guess there is no way to open a pdf file in app without actually using any libraries. Example if I were to use MuPDF, and from their website [link](http://www.mupdf.com/), in the Licensing section it states that it is GPL Licensed and For commercial licensing please contact sales@artifex.com. Does that means I have a buy a license ? Even if my app is going to be free ?

Comment: @user1828151 see edited post. Overall, i think its best to mail authors of the particular library (or consult the lawyer, which i assume you dont want to... :)

Comment: Man this is hard. Okay one last question. For some reason, everytime I google something in the line of "android open pdf file in app", it always shows the same result. I mean, it keeps giving me result of libraries. Is there really no way other than to use a library to read a pdf within app ?

Comment: There is no other way to read PDF within app. You have to use library. (or you can open it with external program like Adobe Reader using intent as described in answer above)